# Executing query in parallel cause more time [SQL Server]

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance, parallel.foreach

I have a query which results in 4 - 5 secs when I am executing it with SSMS(2017) and via console application.

But when I run the same query for three-time using **parallel for each** in my console application it results in 15 - 20 secs.

What I am expecting is, Why can't I get the same result time even I run it parallel.

See below i have checked with profiler. The queries were started in same time

[image]

But see the completion time.

[image]

This is my code:

```
int count = 3;
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        Parallel.For(0, count, (index) =>
        {
                string queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Row Count]  FROM (SELECT SUM([dbo_MaximumData].[C1]) AS [Grid_Column_0],[dbo_MaximumData].[C3] AS [Grid_Column_2],[dbo_MaximumData].[C5] AS [Grid_Column_3],[dbo_MaximumData].[C6] AS [Grid_Column_4],[dbo_MaximumData].[C6] AS [Grid_Column_1] FROM [dbo].[MaximumData] AS [dbo_MaximumData] GROUP BY [dbo_MaximumData].[C3],[dbo_MaximumData].[C5],[dbo_MaximumData].[C6],[dbo_MaximumData].[C6] ) [Main Table] ";
            string connectionString = "Server=””;Database=ODBC ANSI;User Id=sa;Password=Test@123;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();


                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                try
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.Close();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
});

        watch.Stop();
        var str = watch.Elapsed;
```

My question is "**Why the parallel query execution cause more time**"?

Anyone, please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server already knows how to run queries utilizing parallelism. More likely than not, you're just asking the same processors to do three times as much work, simply resulting in (roughly) three times the execution time. Try adding `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to your query to force the use of only one processor and see if that changes anything.

Comment: How many cores on the database server?

Comment: @JeroenMostert: It causes more time than previous. Now I am getting 25 - 27 secs

Comment: Yes, of course it increases the time -- my point was to compare the running time of one instance with `MAXDOP(1)` to three instances with `MAXDOP(1)`. Assuming your server has three or more cores, you should find the speedup to be linear. If it's *not*, then your facing a different issue (blocking from other queries). The point here is that SQL Server is already doing its best to run your query as fast as possible -- it can't run three copies of it in the same time.

Comment: @DanGuzman: it is four.

Comment: Assuming the query is purely CPU bound, it could be either the 4 core machine is a VM and you're only getting one thread or SQL Server is configured to use a single processor.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thanks. So the resulting time depends on core availability right? But even there is four core and no other application consumes in the server machine, why I am getting such delay? is there any other workload to SQL engine when making the parallel call?

Comment: Let's say your query actually takes 20 seconds to execute using one core. SQL Server, being the good friend that it is, helpfully decides to use all 4 cores to speed up your query, by (roughly) chopping the table up in 4 parts and counting that. Now your query takes only 5 seconds, and SQL Server is quite proud. But now you come, and ask it to do that three times in parallel. Problem -- there aren't 12 cores available all of a sudden, but still only 4. And so your three queries now take 5 * 3 = 15 seconds (actually more due to threading overhead). You want more speed, you'll need more CPU.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Clear. Thanks for your time and help friend :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind parallel processing is distributing the cpu/memory/whatever resource load between systems/cores/etc.

What you are doing here is running the same query `count` times. This will cause burden to the database, and will cause you to wait until `count` instances of the same query is executed.

Note that this answer has actually very few things to do with the database itself - it would be the same if you tried to do any *nondistributed* algorithm inside the parallel-for.

Comment: Hi @george: Thanks for your time. Do you mean I have to do some configuration with my database to get the result in quick time? If yes, can you please share those way?

Comment: Not really. You should just execute your query outside the parallel-for. I don't really know if C# has some functions which you can use inside a parallel-for and will be automatically parallelized for you, but sql queries are certainly not of that kind.